# Problems with the ggcorr function to perform square correlation matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, correlation, data-analysis

I am trying to make a square matrix in which the upper triangular part contains the numerical values of the correlation and the lower triangular part the corresponding colors using Pearson's method.

```
library(ggcorrplot)
library(corrplot)
dadosp=head(iris)[1:4]
matcor <- round(cor(dadosp), 2)# matcor
ggcorr(matcor,palette = "Greys", 
       name = expression(rho),method=c("pairwise","pearson"),
      max_size = 10,legend.position = " ",
       min_size = 2,position="triangsuperior",
       size = 3,
       hjust = 0.75,
       nbreaks = 6,
       angle = -45)
```

However, the following error appears:

```
Erro: Can't find `position` called 'triangsuperior'
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The example in which I intend to reproduce would be in structural terms similar to the one below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
corrplot.mixed(matcor)
```

Are you looking for this?

[image]

Comment: The corrplot function does not use Pearson's correlation. My interest is to work using the ggcorr function.

Comment: @BrenoG. what do you mean by "The corrplot function does not use Pearson's correlation" please?  You can supply `corrplot` a correlation matrix using Pearson's

Comment: Typer; if the numbers are to be in the upper triangle then can use for example, `corrplot.mixed(cc, lower="square", upper="number")`

Answer (score 1):

The plot you are showing is from corrplot. Below is kind of a hack for ggcorrplot (OP's question seems to be confused between ggcorr from GGally and ggcorrplot):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggcorrplot)

dadosp=head(iris)[1:4]
matcor <- round(cor(dadosp), 2)# matcor
#set the diagonal to be zero first
diag(matcor) = 0

g = ggcorrplot(matcor,method="circle",type="upper",show.diag=TRUE)

# now we add the text and plot on top of the diagonal to give the lables

g + geom_text(aes(x=Var2,y=Var1,label=value)) + 
geom_label(data=. %>% filter(Var1==Var2),aes(label=Var1)) +
theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

Or using ggcorr from GGally:

```
library(GGally)

n = ncol(dadosp)+1

g = ggcorr(dadosp,geom="circle")

g + geom_vline(xintercept=seq(1.5,n+0.5,by=1)) + 
geom_hline(yintercept=seq(1.5,n+0.5,by=1)) +
geom_text(aes(x=y,y=x,label=round(coefficient,2)),col="steelblue")
```

[image]